# Windows 7 sleep/hibernate not working with dual boot

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, sleep, hibernate

I have a Lenovo W520 laptop with a SSD in the main bay and an external HDD in the 'cd' bay. I have the following setup

- Windows on SSD
- Ubuntu on HDD

I used to have a bit of a stupid setup: the bootloader was on the SSD pointing to GRUB on the HDD, which meant that I could not boot my computer unless both hard disks were present. I figured I could fix this by having both hard disks as bootable: I put Windows' own bootloader on the SSD with Windows Startup Recovery, and did a fresh Ubuntu install on the HDD. However, for some reason, both Sleep and Hibernation aren't working anymore!

The symptons are as follows: I click 'sleep' or 'hibernate' or close the lid, at which point the screen will fade to black (as expected). However, that's all it does; the screen cannot be turned on again, and pressing buttons will just make it 'ping'. After a while, the laptop will simply power off.

I tried the following things:

- Update driver software for the NVIDIA graphics and the Lenovo Power Management
- Update BIOS
- Change boot order in BIOS
- Convert all other partitions from primary to logical
- Boot via the HDD via GRUB instead of booting the SSD directly
- Check and reset power management options

But to no avail. Can someone give me some pointers on

- How to identify the problem, and more importantly
- How do I get my laptop to sleep and hibernate again?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by KernSafe TotalMounter. Uninstalling this solved the issue.